# CSS transition on :hover to display div

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

Since I am a beginner, I am really struggling with this.

Can you tell me how I can transition the `position` of the `.box` when hovering?

I could only display it, but I couldn't `transition` the `position` from `bottom` to `top` which is what I want to do.

```css
.more {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 43px;
  width: 169px;
  top: 50px;
  transition: top 5s;
}

.more:hover .box {
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1  more">
  <a href="#" class="paragraphs " id="xx">More</a>
  <div class="box">
    <span>Pages</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "top"?

Comment: well I gave the position relative so using property top  I think should do to change the position ,but I don't really know

Comment: could you add more of your `HTML` so I can see where more things are positioned on page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `visibility` instead of `display`. Visibility works a bit better with transitions.

```css
.more {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 43px;
  width: 169px;
  top: 50px;
  transition: top 5s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.more:hover .box {
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1  more">
  <a href="#" class="paragraphs " id="xx">More</a>
  <div class="box">
    <span>Pages</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Transition works by interpolating between the old value and then new value.  The issue that you're seeing here is technically the old value was never applied in the first place.

Setting `.box` to `display: none` was basically saying, "don't render this at all," and transition can't transition between something that doens't exist and another value.  Using `visibility` instead of `display` fixes the issue since `visibility: hidden` only hides the element, not removing it completely.

```css
.more {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 43px;
  width: 169px;
  top: 50px;
  transition: top 5s;
}

.more:hover .box {
  top: 100px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1  more">
  <a href="#" class="paragraphs " id="xx">More</a>
  <div class="box">
    <span>Pages</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the transition to work in reverse, then you can add another transition delaying the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
you can easily change the margin in the box class if you want and the speed in the transition :)

```
 .box {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  margin-top:400px;
}
.more:hover .box {
    margin-top:0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```